# Exclude overlapping events (start/end) while considering the venue_id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
events
- id
- venue_id
- starts_at
- ends_at
```

I found this constraint https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE but I'm not sure I understand how I can use it to prevent the creation of overlapping events while considering the `venue_id` so that there can be overlapping events, but not for the same venues.

For example:

`EXCLUDE USING gist (tsrange(starts_at, ends_at)` and somehow consider venue_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the "overlapping" of the timestamp range with an `=` operator on the `venue_id`

```
alter table events 
   add constraint no_overlapping_events
   exclude using gist (venue_id with =, tsrange(starts_at, ends_at) with &&)
```

Note that this requires the [bree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) extension due to the use of the `=` operator

Comment: Thank you! I will update my database to enable `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`